# Vue-Masonry-Wall package: How to use with NuxtJS2 and SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use [**vue-masonry-wall**](https://github.com/fuxingloh/vue-masonry-wall) in my NuxtJS (v2.15.7) app to give it a masonry layout. According to the [docs](https://github.com/fuxingloh/vue-masonry-wall#nuxt-ssr), the vue-masonry-wall package is "SSR friendly". It states to simply add `:ssr="{columns: 2}"` to masonry so that during SSR, it will be loaded in 2 columns.

I tried this in my code ([**codesandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-masonrywall-h55wy?file=/components/Tutorial.vue)). But, during SSR, nothing is loaded.

**Anyone got any idea on what is happening and why I can't see any of the items? It works fine in client-mode.**

Code example:

```html
<vue-masonry-wall :items="items" :options="{width: 300, padding: 12}" :ssr="{columns: 2}" @append="append">
  <template v-slot:default="{item}">
    <div class="item">
      <h5>{{item.title}}</h5>
      <p>{{item.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</vue-masonry-wall>
```

Comment: Yeah, this issue seems to be un-resolved. Even lowering the package version did not help. The content is just empty. https://github.com/fuxingloh/vue-masonry-wall/issues/9

Comment: Thx for checking! Always appreciate your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run it just on the client side, so:

1- if loaded as plugin, globally: name the plugin file ending with ".client", for instance: 'vue-masonry-wall.client.js'

2- if used as module, you can wrap it with the  tag.